# R Build won't find correct version of package

Tags: r, build, dependencies, package

I have two locations for R-Packages on a server.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/jakobr/.R/library"     "/opt/R/R-3.1.2/lib/R/library"
```

I set the `.libPaths()` in `~/.Rprofile` and usually everything works fine.
When I use `attachNamespace(pckgB)` or `library(pckgB)`, `sessionInfo()` tells me I have the version I want. However in `/opt/R/R-3.1.2/lib/R/library` there is an outdated version of `pckgB` when I want to build `pckgA` which needs the updated version of `pckgB` it tells me

```
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘pckgB’ 1.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘pckgA’
```

How can I get R to ignore the directory `/opt/R/R-3.1.2/lib/R/library` which I don't have writing access to.